# C - Array of strings to an array of char

Tags: c, vigenere

In C, I need to take a single string argument from `argv []` and put it into another array so that I can iterate over the chars. How do I do this?

(this is to implement a Veginere Cypher FYI)

Comment: You don't need to copy it into another array; you already have a string (each element of `argv`), just iterate over it.

Comment: why not just use a `char string[size]` array and then you can do stuff like `string[i]`, and increment `i` until you hit a NULL character?

Comment: `strcpy()` was created to copy strings between different arrays. Use it. **Make sure the destination array is large enough.**

Comment: I need to take one of the arguments given at the command line (the shift word) and then iterate over that word to encrypt another message. I cant iterate over the whole of argv itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to iterate over the characters of the `n`th entry in `argv`:

```
int i;
int len = strlen(argv[n]);
for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
    // do something with argv[n][i]
```

If you want to copy them somewhere else first (which is most likely not necessary) use `strcpy()` or `strdup()`.

Comment: You don't need to call `strlen` (just check for the null terminator) and, if you do use `strlen`, get it out of the loop and call it only once.  The call to `strlen` *may* be hoisted out, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @EdS. Good point. Going for the null terminator would be most efficient (and there is a corresponding answer now). I posted the above since I think it's the simplest to understand.

Comment: Or just call `strlen` once (but there's really no need).  It's the difference between an O(n) and an O(n^2) operation.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to copy it into a separate string.

Here is how:

```
// argv is array of strings, or array of array of chars
int main( int argc, char** argv ) // here argv is an array of strings
{
    int i = 0;
    while( 1 )
    {
        if( argv[1][i] == '\0' )
            break; // argv[1][i] <- Current character of the first cmd-line arg
        i++
    }
}
```

or if you would really like to copy it to use a simple string, just set up a pointer to the start of the string like so:

```
char* firstArgument = argv[n]; // where n is the nth command line argument
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy the string.  You don't state that you are mutating the string (though argv is modifiable, I would probably leave it alone), so just iterate over it.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if(argc < some_min_value) {
        print_usage();
        return -1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; argv[str_idx][i]; ++i) {
        char c = argv[str_idx][i];
        /* do something with c */
    }

    return 0;
}
```